# Detect a 3G internet connection in .NET

Tags: .net, networking

Our application downloads data from the internet using RSS but is having connection problems on machines connecting with 3G.  We'd like to detect 3G,EDGE,GPRS connections so that we can change the application behaviour, display warnings or status of connection.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`NetworkInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) class in the `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace should be of some use to you (more specifically, the [`GetAllNetworkInterfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces.aspx) method. An example is shown on the linked MSDN page that demonstrates how to get the type, address, operational status, and other information about every network interface.

Reduced version of MSDN example:

```
public static void ShowNetworkInterfaces()
{
    IPGlobalProperties computerProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    Console.WriteLine("Interface information for {0}.{1}     ",
            computerProperties.HostName, computerProperties.DomainName);
    if (nics == null || nics.Length < 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  No network interfaces found.");
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("  Number of interfaces .................... : {0}", nics.Length);
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(adapter.Description.Length,'='));
        Console.WriteLine("  Interface type .......................... : {0}", adapter.NetworkInterfaceType);
        Console.WriteLine("  Physical Address ........................ : {0}", 
                   adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("  Operational status ...................... : {0}", 
            adapter.OperationalStatus);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but based on these properties, how can you tell if the network interface is 3G/EDGE/GPRS ? I tried to connect a 3G modem to my PC, the NetworkInterfaceType is "Ppp", which doesn't tell if it's a mobile connection.